# comboBox Error 'The value can not be null. Parameter name: item '

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to fill a combobox in the load of my form with data from database .

Here is my function:

```
public void FillCombo()
{
    //remplir code article
    var b = (from l in db.tbl_article
             where l.designiation == designiation.Text
             select l.code_article).SingleOrDefault();

    code_article.Text = b.ToString();

    // remplir combobox article
    var r = from db in db.tbl_article select db.designiation;

    foreach (var i in r)
    {
        designiation.Items.Add(i);
    }

    //remplir combobox service
    var s = from db in db.tbl_service select db.libelle;

    foreach (var i in s)
    {
        service.Items.Add(i);
    }

    //remplir combobox fournisseur
    var fou = from db in db.tbl_fournisseur select db.nom_fournisseur;

    foreach (var i in fou)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(i);       
    }   
}
```

When ever I run my code it stops at this line :

```
 var fou = from db in db.tbl_fournisseur select db.nom_fournisseur;
    foreach (var i in fou)
    { comboBox1.Items.Add(i); }
```

and it returns this error :

> The value can not be null. Parameter name: item

I checked the names and everything. Also my table `tbl_fournisseur` contains values. I really don't get where the problem comes from. Please help I will appreciate it !

Comment: Please put breakpoints on **every one** of your `Items.Add` lines. When the exception is thrown, what is the value of `i` when checked from the `Watch Window` or `Immediate Window`?

Comment: Thank you I used the dubbagging and all the values existed until the mast one ..and finally I found out that the last one is filled with null values that's where the probleme come from .. Thank you Sir for yourhelp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write a query to select items that you want to add and while reading values from the database add them to the combo box.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=;Password=");
conn.Open();
String q = "Select * from table"';
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(q, conn);
SqlDataReader r = command.ExecuteReader();
while(r.read())
{ 
    comboBox1.Items.Add(r["index"].toString());    
}

conn.Close();
```